# Implement Sitecore Rules with Data Exchange Framework

Tags: data-exchange-framework, rules-engine

We followed this nice article to add rules that give friendly names at the `item:created` event and it's working fine.

https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2015/07/13/seo-friendly-urls-in-sitecore-prevention-is-better-than-cure/

But, when we import and create items using DataExchangeFramework (DEF), these Sitecore rules don't work.

How can we use Sitecore rules with DEF while importing the items?

Thanks

Comment: Are you saving items to a location that is not in the rules for the item renaming? I have had these issues before where my rules say for children on item "home", but I am saving an item in "global" that is outside of the home item.

Comment: @ChrisAuer Yes, the rules are looking at the same location as the items. The rules are working on event saving but not on creation.